# How to use Greater than with word

Tags: vba, excel

How could I put a greater than with word.
should I create a function?
I have a excel File with 7 Sheets. One general with all elements and 6 others with Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platin, PlPlus & Ambass

What I want is to say that :

```
Bronze < Silver < Gold < Platin < PlPlus < Ambass
```

and after put a condition which will take in consideration Column D or F 
and say that for example on the Row 10:

```
let's say on my general sheet I have,  D10 = silver
let's say on my general sheet I have,  F10 = gold 
If D10 < F10 then send the entire Row to a special sheet "GOLD" 

let's say on my general sheet I have,  D10 = Platin
let's say on my general sheet I have,  F10 = Bronze
If D10 > F10 then send the entire Row10 to a special sheet "Platin" 

let's say on my general sheet I have, D10 = F10 =silver
if there are the same status send it to the sheet with that status.
```

How could I explain on vba that Bronze is the smallest category after is silver after is gold after is Platin after is PlPlus after is Ambass ??

Comment: give numbers to the words. Bronze = 0, Silver = 1 and so on. Or write a function with if Bronze then valueA = 0, elseif silver then valueA = 1 ; Do that for both, D10 and F10 and then compare them

Answer (score 0):

you could use them on a static sheet and in order from a1 to a# then use the `worksheetfunction.match` to give you the row, or like so `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("gold",array("silver","gold","platinum"))`

```
function metal_rank(strMetal as string) as long
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strMetal,array("silver","gold","platinum"))
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

In a standard VBA module, create a function:

```
Function category(categoryName as String) as Integer
    select case categoryName
        case "Bronze"
            category = 0
        case "Silver"
            category = 1
        case "Gold"
            category = 2
        case "Platin"
            category = 3
        case "PlPlus"
            category = 4
        case "Ambass"
            category = 5
    end select
end function
```

Then, in your calling code you can make your comparisons like this:

```
dim ws as Worksheet    

If category(D10) < category(F10) then
    set ws = worksheets(F10)
else                ' Either category(D10) is greater, or they're equal
    set ws = worksheets(D10)
endif
```

This set the variable ws to the worksheet where you want to write your data.

Comment: it is telling me ByRef argument type dismatch. I want to compare all the cells in the worksheets not only D10 and F10

Comment: How are variables D10 and F10 declared? What sort of values do they have? If by D10 you mean Column D Row 10, use something like Range("D10").value.

Comment: I have one sheet (General) with all the information, I have on the column B all the Room Number and on the column D,F,H, J etc... I have all the Status of the guest. I would like to compare those column D, F, H... And Copy the row to an another Sheet that has the same name as the stronger status. If I row Range(F10) is Silver and Range(G10) is Gold : I would like to copy the entire row 10 to the sheet called GOLD. etc... until all the room are treated. so I will have as well 6 others sheets (Bronze)(Silver)(Gold)(Platin)(PlPlus)(Ambass)

Comment: Palomaes: I'm happy to help you as you work on your project, but you need to break things up into specific questions, and recognize when someone has answered your question. What you're doing now is expanding your original question. Also, you need to show what you've done to attempt to solve the issues yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a helper Function (say, `GetSheetName()`) in your main code, thta accepts two ranges value to compare and returns the sheet name where to "send" data:

```
Sub main()

    With Worksheets(GetSheetName(Range("D10").Value, Range("F10").Value))
        MsgBox .Name
    End With

End Sub
```

so that `GetSheetName()` would be:

```
Function GetSheetName(val1 As String, val2 As String) As String
    Select Case GetRank(UCase(val1)) - GetRank(UCase(val2))
        Case Is < 0
            GetSheetName = val2
        Case Else
            GetSheetName = val1
    End Select
End Function
```

which on its turn uses another helper function to return the *rank* of the passed value

this latter helper function can exploit many different available methods/functions

- `Application.Match` method (as @Natahn_Sav proposed):

  ```
  Function GetRank(val As String) As Long
      GetRank = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(val, Array("Bronze", "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum", "PlPlus", "Ambass"))
  End Function
  ```
- `Switch` function

  ```
  Function GetRank(val As String) As Long
      GetRank = Switch(val = "BRONZE", 0, _
                       val = "SILVER", 1, _
                       val = "GOLD", 2, _
                       val = "PLATIN", 3, _
                       val = "PLPLUS ", 4, _
                       val = "AMBASS", 5)
  End Function
  ```
- `Select Case` syntax

  ```
  Function GetRank(val As String) As Long
      Select Case val
          Case "BRONZE"
              GetRank = 0
          Case "SILVER"
              GetRank = 1
          Case "GOLD"
              GetRank = 2
          Case "PLATIN"
              GetRank = 3
          Case "PLPLUS"
              GetRank = 4
          Case "AMBASS"
              GetRank = 5
      End Select
  End Function
  ```

Comment: @Palomaes, did you get though it?

Comment: the macro is telling me : Compile error  Ambigous name detected: GetRank.   And It is the GetRank from the last one that you put on your answer

Comment: You have to choose only one GetRank function and delete or comment out the other two. Let me know

Comment: it drives me crazy it doesn't work.. because I want to compare the whole column. and it can be send to 6differents sheets not only gold or platin.

Comment: I am a little confused with this function GetRank.. There is 3 of them.. so I need to put on my main Code this : With Worksheets(GetSheetName(Range("D10").Value, Range("F10").Value))
        MsgBox .Name
    End With

Comment: Ok for what you are going to put in your code. As for GetRank() function, just choose only one out of those three I showed you

Comment: What is this "whole column" you are talking about? There's no trace of it in your post code, so please check the solution I gave you against your _original_ request and if it solves it then accept it. And if you have new issues you can always make a new post with all needed details to let people understand it along with your corresponding code attempts